# direct printing in oracle 11g or 12c forms

Tags: oracle, printing, weblogic, oracleforms

i have a point of sale application running on oracle weblogic 11g 10.3.6 or 12c 12.2.1.4
i need to directly print the point of sale receipt on the thermal printer next to the salesman without showing it in PDF format.
is there any process to apply to do this?
thanks
khaled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You linked Oracle Forms as a tag, so I'm answering from that perspective. You need to use something similar to example 3 from this [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/formsandreports/use-reports/pbr_cla005.htm#RSPUB23806). The key is using DESTYPE=printer and DESNAME is the name of the printer on your network.

```
Example 3: Sending report output to a printer

rwrun report=test.rdf userid=scott/tiger@mydb destype=printer
desname=myprinter

http://myias.mycomp.com:7779/reports/rwservlet?server=myrepserv+report=test.rdf+
userid=scott/tiger@mydb+destype=printer+desname=myprinter

rwclient server=myrepserv report=test.rdf userid=scott/tiger@mydb destype=printer desname=myprinter
```

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful replay, it worked fine, but it's taking around 30 seconds to print.if there is any advice or tips to enhance the printing performance it would be appreciated.